# Get CKEditor Data with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor, twig

I have a problem getting CKEditor value with Jquery. When I open the console, I have `Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined`. 
I looked at the code rendered and ckEditor seem to be not rendered when the script part is there. When I remove the script part, it's rendered well in HTML. Whether the script is there or not, CKEditor is on the page and working, I only see the difference in HTML.

**My code:**

```
{{ form_start(form, {'id': 'formCorrection'~reponse.id}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.commentaire, {'id': 'commentaire'~reponse.id}) }} 
{{ form_row(form.submit) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script>
    var idCommentaire = 'commentaire{{ reponse.id }}';
    var commentaire = CKEDITOR.instances[idCommentaire].getData();
    $("#formCorrection{{ reponse.id }}").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('paces_colle_correctioncolleqr_sauvegardercorrectionpassage') }}",
            data: {commentaire: commentaire}
        })
    });
</script>
```

**With script part :**

```
<textarea id="commentaire1148472" name="paces_colle_correctioncolleqr_correctionreponseqr[commentaire]" required="required" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
```

**Without the script part :**

```
<textarea id="commentaire1148472" name="paces_colle_correctioncolleqr_correctionreponseqr[commentaire]" class="ckeditor" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
<div id="cke_commentaire1148472" class="cke_1 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_commentaire1148472 cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit" dir="ltr" lang="fr" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_commentaire1148472_arialbl">['ckEditor stuff']</div>
```

Comment: Did you instantiate the editor before trying to do `getData`? I don't see that part in your current code

Comment: Yes, it is instantiated in the base template (it's a twig template).

All is working well except that I can't getData with JQuery. I used the same script code in another place to get data of CKEditor with jquery and it's working. The only difference is the rendered HTML. With the script on this page, I don't know why, the CKEditor code is not there but it's displayed on the page.

Comment: Reading through the documentation you should be able to access the data with `var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();`

Comment: It returns an empty string.

Comment: You switched it out to `$('#'+idCommentaire+'.editor').val();` right?

Comment: I tried `document.getElementById(idCommentaire).value` and `$('#'+idCommentaire+'.editor').val()`. The first returns an empty string, the second returns undefined

Comment: Found it ! It was because I was getting Data from CKEditor before submit. I put the code inside the submit function and it's working now. Thank you !